# Following the documentation and trying to upgrade from 3.0.1 to 8.0.4 gives undefined error

Tags: highcharts

--> I tried to follow your documentation. We use backbone and requirejs. I downloaded the gradle package using

```
compile 'org.webjars:highcharts:8.0.4'
```

--> Inside requirejs configuration file I added below:

````
packages: [{
      name: 'highcharts',
      main: 'highcharts'
  }],

'highcharts': '../../webjars/highcharts/8.0.4/highcharts',
    'highcharts-exporting': '../../webjars/highcharts/8.0.4/modules/exporting',
    'highcharts-accessibility': '../../webjars/highcharts/8.0.4/modules/accessibility',
    'highchartsCommon':'./highchartsCommon',```

--> highchartsCommon.js below:
```
define ([ 'highcharts',
    'highcharts-exporting',
    'highcharts-accessibility'] , require([
    'highcharts',
    'highcharts-exporting',
    'highcharts-accessibility'
    ], function (highchart)
        {
            window.Highcharts= highchart;
            return highchart;
        }
));

define(['abcd', 'xyza', 'abdc12', 'hxhxh', 'highchartsCommon', 'jquery'], function (Abcd, Ayza, Abcd12, Hxhxh, Highcharts) {

console.log(Highcharts.chart);
        var optionsSample = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'bar'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [1, 0, 4]
            }]
        };
      this.chart = new Highcharts.Chart(optionsSample);
````

I get undefined for the console log output and the I get Type Error cannot find the function Chart.

Exception is  `Uncaught TypeError: Highcharts.Chart is not a constructor`
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Hi @Bootham Deyyam, Which documentation did you follow? What is the result of `console.log(Highcharts);` in your case?

Comment: I am following https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts#load-highcharts-from-the-cdn-as-an-amd-module, also using the readMe from the downloaded package. I get Highcharts as undefined with the above print statement. I just changed my version to 6.2.0 it is working. I am upgrading it to 7.2.1 now. I will check if that works for me.

Comment: I worked for 7.0.0 but it starts to fail from 7.1.0

Comment: I worked for 7.0.3 but it starts to fail from 7.1.0

Comment: [This demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g6sbpcqy/) works fine. Please add a live example of the problem you have. Please check the result of `console.log(typeof Highcharts)`. It should be an `object` and when it is a `function` then your environment might be running on the back-end (like in NextJS) or something was loaded in the wrong way.

Comment: I am getting this error trying to use the above demo example.

Comment: I figured out the issue, I had to upgrade requireJs version to latest version